# do something after killProcess in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i need to kill my app to refresh it to prevent force stop because the 2 fragments call objects from our server. what i want is for my app to refresh after the video on a fragment is finished. what i did is put

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

after `fragmentTransaction.commit();`. but what it does is it shows the video fragment again. the same thing happen when i put killProcess after the method call for fragment change(i am using handler-runnable to change my fragment). so, does killProcess also kill the variables. i can't find anything about this stuff.

here's my code:

```
public class fragChangeView extends AppCompatActivity {
    FrameLayout frmLayout;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    FragmentManager fm;
    int fragNum;
    Handler handler;
    private LuksloftsFunc lFunc;
    int changeFragDelay, changeFragDelay2;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    int durationFromVidLen;
    Long longChangeDelay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag_change_view);

        frmLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frmFragLayout);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String actName = i.getStringExtra("actName");

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        handler = new Handler();

        retriever.setDataSource("http://*video ip*/api/extras/permit_video.mp4", new HashMap<String, String>());
        String vidLen = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        durationFromVidLen = Integer.parseInt(vidLen);

        lFunc = LuksloftsFunc.getInstance(this);
        changeFragDelay = Integer.parseInt(lFunc.getTimezoneCurrencyInterval());
        longChangeDelay = Long.parseLong(lFunc.getTimezoneCurrencyInterval());
        lFunc.updateAppLastRefreshTime();

        //startAlarmFragChange();

        switch (actName){
            case "video":
                PermitVideoFrag frag1 = new PermitVideoFrag();
                ft.replace(R.id.frmFragLayout, frag1);
                ft.commit();
                fragNum = 1;
                break;
            case "timezone":
                ForexTimezoneFrag frag2 = new ForexTimezoneFrag();
                ft.replace(R.id.frmFragLayout, frag2);
                ft.commit();
                fragNum = 2;
                break;
        }
        try{
            handler.post(changeFrag);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    public void startAlarmFragChange(){
        //start alarmmanager fragChanger
        AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), AlarmFragChange.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(), 0, intent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, System.currentTimeMillis(), longChangeDelay, pi);
        //end alarmmanager fragChanger
    }

    public void stopAlarmFragChange(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), AlarmFragChange.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }

    public void fragChanger(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            switch (fragNum) {
                case 1:
                    ForexTimezoneFrag frag2 = new ForexTimezoneFrag();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frmFragLayout, frag2);
                    fragNum = 2;
                    changeFragDelay2 = changeFragDelay;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    PermitVideoFrag frag1 = new PermitVideoFrag();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frmFragLayout, frag1);
                    fragNum = 1;
                    changeFragDelay2 = durationFromVidLen;
                    break;
            }
            try {
                ft.commit();
                Log.d("log1", "error on commit");
                /*if(lFunc.IsNeedAppRefresh()) {
                   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }*/
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
    }

    private Runnable changeFrag = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fragChanger();
            /*if(lFunc.IsNeedAppRefresh()) {

                Log.d("", "after kill process");
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }*/
            //handler.postDelayed(changeFrag, changeFragDelay);
            handler.postDelayed(changeFrag, changeFragDelay2);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If you feel like you need to force an Android process to exit, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: no, i don't intend my app to exit, i just want it to refresh after a set time.

Comment: How do you define what a "refresh" is?  What exactly do you want to see happen without killing the process?

Comment: ah, sorry. what i want is to clear my apps memory allocation so that the devices memory would have more free space. i that the app and the device to run as smooth as possible

Comment: You generally don't have to worry about that for memory taken by Activities and Fragments.  Android will manage the memory for you by killing off Activities that are no longer visible when resources are needed.

Comment: but my app force stops after long execution. how long do android manage those activities

Comment: It sounds like you have a bug to fix before anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107587/discussion-between-rmanalo-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: but i don't see anything that might cause a bug

Comment: You said your app force stops.  That sounds like a bug.

Comment: i remember that ft.commit causes an error saying commit is already called. what i did is put commit outside the switch case and put it inside a try-catch. also do text with image marquee web service cause an error after long executions because our app force stops after a long time running and i didn't handle that part so i don't know what to do about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured out what to do. i updated the code like this;

```
public void fragChanger(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        String fragName = "";
            switch (fragNum) {
                case 1:
                    ForexTimezoneFrag frag2 = new ForexTimezoneFrag();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frmFragLayout, frag2);
                    fragNum = 2;
                    fragName = "forex";
                    changeFragDelay2 = changeFragDelay;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    PermitVideoFrag frag1 = new PermitVideoFrag();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frmFragLayout, frag1);
                    fragNum = 1;
                    fragName = "video";
                    changeFragDelay2 = durationFromVidLen;
                    break;
            }
            try {
                ft.commit();
                Log.d("log1", "fragName: "+fragName);
                if(lFunc.IsNeedAppRefresh()) {
                    Log.d("log1", "app will refresh");
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("log1", "error on commit");

            }
    }
```

i could also put it before `break;`. it still works the same. thanks men.